# Custom loss function with multiple additional inputs in TF 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Struggling to get a simple custom loss function with multiple additional inputs and batch size of 1 working.

In the toy example below I'm creating a dataset of length n = 2, with two different inputs and one dummy label.
I would like to pass one sample, containing both inputs to my custom loss function where I would like to process them (hence the batch size = 1).

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, Input
from tensorflow.keras import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as kb

shape = (3,3)
x1 = tf.ones(shape) * 2 + tf.random.uniform(shape, -0.1, 0.1)
x2 = tf.ones(shape) * 3 + tf.random.uniform(shape, -0.1, 0.1)
y1 = tf.ones(shape)
y2 = tf.ones(shape)    

# these inputs don't work
labels = tf.stack([[1/2], [1/3]])
in1_data = tf.stack([x1, x2])
in2_data = tf.stack([y1, y2]) 
# these inputs work (since label is a scalar and gets broadcasted?)
# labels = tf.stack([[1/2]])
# in1_data = tf.stack([x1])
# in2_data = tf.stack([y1])     

def custom_loss_wrapper(in1, in2):
    def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # the problem is here
        out1 = in1 * y_pred
        return tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error(out1, in2)
    return custom_loss    

in1 = Input(shape=(3,3),name='in1')
in2 = Input(shape=(3,3),name='in2')
x = Flatten()(in1)
x = Dense(3, activation='relu')(x)
y = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)    

model = Model(inputs=[in1, in2], outputs=y)
model.summary()
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss=custom_loss_wrapper(in1, in2))
model.fit([in1_data, in2_data], labels, batch_size=1, steps_per_epoch=10)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2,1] vs. [2,3,3]
 [[{{node loss_26/dense_120_loss/mul}}]]
```

which means my loss function is receiving both of my samples rather than just one, but no idea what I'm doing wrong. Can't get printing working in the loss function either.